# AppFabric Caching Service keeps crashing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, service, cache

I got a message from SharePoint that the AppFabric Caching Service was down. When I went to Services to restart it, it restarted fine, but shut down within a few seconds. I went into the Event Viewer, and got the message:

> The AppFabric Caching Service service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 626 
>   time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart
>   the service.

It continues to crash and restart, and I'm not sure where to look.

Other info: I recently renamed the server using `Rename-SPServer`

Comment: Is the AppFabric Caching Service using a specific service account? If yes, you might need to deal with SPNs settings since you renamed your server.

Comment: @Trevor Newhook: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the instance and re-add it.
Try these commands:

```
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Then

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

see if this helps. It helped me although I did not rename my servers.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you have to do.

1. You have to clear the config cache on the all server in the farm(if you have more than one server in farm).
2. Try to repair the Distributed Cache host. Follow the instruction from below technet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx#repair

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't seem to work. The AppFabric Caching Service service continues to crash.